# Vectorspace - Subspaces with Intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the following holds for Subspaces $U_1\cap (U_2 + U_3) = (U_1\cap U_2) + U_3$ iff $U_3$ is a subset of $U_1$.

I did the proof but I just can't think of an example where this doesn't hold, can someone give me one or two examples where both set inclusions don't hold?

Comment: Let U_1,U_2 be the null set and U_3 the real numbers. I think this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an “if and only if”, just take $U_3\not\subseteq U_1$.

For instance, let $U_1=\{0\}$ and $U_3\ne\{0\}$. Then
$$
U_1\cap(U_2+U_3)=\{0\}
$$
whereas
$$
(U_1\cap U_2)+U_3=U_3
$$
This provides a case where $(U_1\cap U_2)+U_3\not\subseteq U_1\cap(U_2+U_3)$. It shouldn't be difficult to find one where the other inclusion doesn't hold.